# How to open specific payment application in flutter based on the uri string?

Tags: android, flutter, android-intent, url-launcher

My requirement is like, **I have to display list of installed application which supports payment as list using flutter and click on the specific application icon will redierct it to application itself**.

I am able to list down the payment methods. Also, I have integrated the necessary payment gateway to create the intent_url based on the amount entered. So, now, I have selected the application name(package name) and URI string **(tez://pay?sn=....)** with me. But when I use url_launcher, it will ask which app do you want to select for further payment. But In my case, My API will create intent_url specifically, So, it should be redirected to that app directly. But I failed to do so using **url_lancher**.

Another alternative I found is to choose the **android_intent** and **andoird_intent_plus** flutter package but it is also throwing an error as attached below.

[image]

**Is there any one who can help me to open specific intent_url to specific payment app.**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't post text as image